# Writing methods that call other methods inside d3 ember components?

Tags: ember.js, d3.js

Let's say I am creating a reusable component in Ember, and I want a helper function that calls another helper function defined within.  For example,

```
App.SomeCoolComponent = Ember.Component.extend

  offset: 50

  position: (x) -> x * 100

  offsetPosition: # would like (x) -> position(x) + offset
```

So conceptually, return a function that would evaluate the position at x, add offset, and return value.  Obviously this is a silly example and I could just write `offSetPosition` without calling `position`, but in a more complex scenario that is repeating code.  The problem is I can't figure out how to get this to work.  I tried

```
  offsetPosition: (x) -> @get('position')(x) + @get('offset')
```

which fails because `@get` isn't defined within the function, it has the wrong scope.  I've tried to insert things like `Ember.computed` in various places also with no luck, e.g. the following also doesn't work:

```
  offsetPosition: Ember.computed(->
    (x) -> @get('position')(x) + @get('offset')).property('position', 'offset')
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Ember version 1.3.0-beta.1+canary.48513b24. Thanks in advance!

**Edit: seems like my problem stems from passing the function into a d3 call.  For example:**

```
App.SomeCoolComponent = Ember.Component.extend

  offset: 50

  position: (d, i) -> i * 100

  offsetPosition: (d, i) ->
    @position(d, i) + @get('offset')

  # Some other code not shown

  didInsertElement: ->
    data = [1, 2, 3]
    i = 1
    d = data[i]
    console.log(@position(d, i)) # works
    console.log(@offsetPosition(d, i)) # works

    d3.select('svg').selectAll('circle').data(data).enter().append('circle')
      .attr('cx', @position) # works
      .attr('cy', @offsetPosition) # fails
      .attr('r', 30)
```

The error message is `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGCircleElement> has no method 'position'`

Any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a function `offsetPosition` (which references `this` and expects it to point to `App.SomeCoolComponent`) to a D3 callback where `this` is replaced by the `DOMElement`.

You can solve the problem in two ways:

1. Using the [`fat arrow syntax`](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow):

   ```
   d3.select('svg').selectAll('circle').data(data).enter().append('circle')
     .attr('cx', @position) # works
     .attr('cy', (d, i) => @offsetPosition(d, i))
     .attr('r', 30)
   ```
2. Using `bind` explicitly:

   ```
   d3.select('svg').selectAll('circle').data(data).enter().append('circle')
     .attr('cx', @position) # works
     .attr('cy', @offsetPosition.bind(this))
     .attr('r', 30)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

methods (aka not computed properties) are in the current context and should just be called like a method, and not with getters/setters.

offsetPosition: (x) ->
  @position(x) + @get("offset")

position: (x) ->
  x * 100

Here's an example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eWIYICu/3/edit

```
App.AnAppleComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  offset: 50,

  position: function(x) {
    return x * 100;
  },

  offsetPosition: function(x) {
    return this.position(x) + this.get('offset');
  },

  displayOffset: function(){
    return this.offsetPosition(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  }.property('offset')

});
```

Personally I'd create a mixin and add my methods in there, then add the mixin wherever that logic is needed.  Mixins are in the scope of whatever they are added to.

**BTW You can use Ember.Get(object, 'propertyOnObject') anywhere in the app.**

In response to your edit, you are passing in methods into those attribute values instead of the values of those methods (which is why it works above, but not below).  There is a good chance since you are sending in those methods jquery is applying those methods later way out of scope.

```
didInsertElement: ->
  data = [1, 2, 3]
  i = 1
  d = data[i]
  position = @position(d, i)
  offsetPosition = @offsetPosition(d, i)
  console.log position
  console.log offsetPosition
  d3.select("svg").selectAll("circle").data(data).enter().append("circle").attr("cx", position).attr("cy", offsetPosition).attr "r", 30
```

I have a feeling you are wanting this to dynamically update or something along those lines, if that's the case you really want to be using computed properties, the bacon of Ember.  Here's an updated version of the apple component:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/eWIYICu/5/edit

```
<div {{bind-attr style='dynamicStyle'}}>

dynamicStyle: function(){
  var rgb = this.get('rgb'),
      rgb1 = rgb * 21 % 255,
      rgb2 = rgb * 32 % 255,
      rgb3 = rgb * 41 % 255;
  return 'background-color:rgb(' + rgb1 + ',' + rgb2 + ',' + rgb3 + ');';
}.property('rgb'),
```

Comment: Thanks for the response!  So it seems like the problem is more complicated.  What you wrote indeed works as written, but it doesn't work in my actual app, as soon as I attempt to pass the function into a d3 command.  I'll edit the original post with details.